# how to store file entries into adjacency list

Tags: java, file, adjacency-list

I have an adjacency matrix of a graph in a file.how to store this adjacency matix in a two dimensional matrix
my input file looks like

```
e 1 36
e 2 45
e 3 74
e 4 18
e 5 36
e 6 74
e 6 45
e 6 136
e 6 36
e 6 21
e 6 18
e 7 18
e 7 116
e 7 74
e 7 99
e 7 81
e 7 135
```

i need a output  as adjacency list:

```
1-->36
2-->45
3-->74
4-->18
5-->36
6-->74-->45-->136-->36-->21-->18
7-->18-->116--->74-->99-->81-->135
```

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Graph1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int linecount = 0, ec = 0;
        String nbin = null, cbin = null;
        int[][] data = null;
        String e = "e";
        System.out.println("Graph Coloring Algorithm Test\n");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter graph input file name: ");
        String newfile = sc.nextLine() + ".txt";
        File file = new File(newfile);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while ((scan.hasNext())) {
            StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(scan.nextLine());
            if (t.nextToken().equals(e)) {
                ec++;
                nbin = scan.nextInt();
                cbin = scan.nextInt();
            }
            linecount++;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
                    {
                        data[nbin][cbin] = 1;
                    }
                }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
                {
                    System.out.print(data[i][j]);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

this code is having error .how to convert the string token to integer
I how can I accept a line from file which starts with **e** and add it to the adjacency list.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried.

Comment: how to separate data entries starting with e?

Comment: Anything you've tried is useful for us to give you an answer.

Comment: May I suggest the [scanner documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and the [Basic I/O guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)?

Comment: edited my code.i'm a beginner.this code is not working.please try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

At line 19 in your code you shouldn't use `scan.nextLine()` instead you should use `scan.next()` since it is a iterator you're working with.

And also at line 22, 23 you use `scan.nextInt()` and try to appeal it to a String. And unless you want the user to input a Integer you should use the same String you specified on line 19. I assume you mean the integers after 'e' so you would need to do this instead:

```
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(scan.next());
            if (t.nextToken().equals(e)) {
                ec++;
                nbin = Integer.valueOf(t.nextToken());
                cbin =  Integer.valueOf(t.nextToken());
            }
```

You would need to change nbin & cbin to integers in order for it to work. And your two-dimensional array is always null. You need to add `int[][] data = new int[Your First Size][Your Second Size];`

And your logic to compute the adjacency list wouldn't work because according to your "matrix input file" the integers are way bigger than 0-5. Instead I suggest you should use [Maps.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Okay this will get you closer to your goal, but you need to do it yourself in order to understand and learn something so I'll leave you with this.

See also:  [Java Docummentations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: i'm trying to implement the graph using adjacency list.this is a code for adjacency matrix.thnks for the clarification.even though there was some errors i got the correct adjacency matrix